# Should we undelete this answer?

Tags: discussion, specific-answer, deleted-answers, undelete

So, backstory first...

Once upon a time there was a new CR user. This user posted a number of spammy answers in a short period of time. All of them linked back to his company's website. Most of them were really nothing more, but then there was [this answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/94651/41243).  This answer actually has a good bit of merit to it, particularly after Jamal edited the spam link out of it.

I tried to vote to undelete it, only to realize that it had been moderator deleted, so I couldn't. I suspect the answer was nuked along with the user, but I'm just speculating. Anyway, it's a good answer. I think we should undelete it. Thoughts?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

## Yes

The answer doesn't have much information, but the information that is there seems like it provides some useful advice. It could probably use a little editing after being un-deleted. (if that's what happens.)

## No

Look at the above answer. This answer is a copy-paste from that.

Comment: You beat me to it. I agree with it and it is quite an interesting answer. Even though it has some lack of "meat".

Comment: Good catch! I hadn't noticed that!

Comment: Yes, it's just another tactic used by spammers.  Had it been legitimate, I wouldn't have deleted the post and destroyed the user.